# Epanechnikov in R

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Suppose I have one data point, $x_1=0$ and I estimate the Epanechnikov kernel using bandwith $h=1$. The formula is then:

$\hat f(x,1)=\frac{3}{4}(1-x^2)$ for $|x|\leq1$

I use the code: `density(x=0, bw=1, kernel=c("epanechnikov"))`

Yet, I get that instead of getting the parabola from $-1$ to $1$, it has a larger domain. Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bandwidth in kernel density estimation is a matter of definition -- it varies from book to book and implementation to implementation (more specifically, it's a multiple of some unit bandwidth, and the exact definition of the kernel for a bandwidth of 1 is the thing that varies). You're not using the definition that the function you're calling uses; they clearly state what they're doing.

They specify it in the help on the function under `Arguments`:

```
    bw  
         the smoothing bandwidth to be used. The kernels are scaled such that  
         this is the standard deviation of the smoothing kernel. (Note this   
         differs from the reference books cited below, and from S-PLUS.)
```

For the Epanechnikov kernel, this means specifying `bw=1` defines the density corresponding to that kernel to be nonzero on $(-\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5})$.

This choice makes the same bandwidth on different kernels have more-or-less similar effects.

[image: plot of different kernels with standard deviation one]

Comment: So if I specify `bw=sqrt(1/5)` I get the graph from $-1$ to $1$. So what's the relation between the $h$ parameter and $bw$?

Comment: Typically, $h$ is a bandwidth. The `density` function doesn't have aparameter called `h`, it calls it `bw`, which is as I already explained, clearly defined. Since both $h$ and `bw` are simply notations for bandwidth parameters, my opening sentences above applies ... so if you want me to compare it with some other unit kernel, *which* definition of the unit kernel, $K$ are you using?

Comment: I have edited my first sentence in the answer; perhaps that will clarify it.